# What are the default location for an anaconda / miniconda installations on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, conda, miniconda

I need to figure out for our software, where could Anaconda or Miniconda install itself on Windows platforms. I need this, to not bother the user by asking the location of they installation, if it is the default.

So far I found, that the `C:\Users\username\AnacondaX` (`C:\Users\username\MinicondaX`) is the default on my machine, if I choose install only for my user, or `C:\ProgramData\AnacondaX` (`C:\AppData\MinicondaX`). if I choose installation for all users. (X here can be either 2 or 3 - for python2 or python3).

But I'm not sure, that this applies for all Windows machines, or they could be other possible locations. *So my question is: are there more possible default locations, where Conda (Anaconda/Miniconda) could possibly install itself?*

Thanks for the answers!

Comment: I think you mean the default installation path because manually the user can install it almost anywhere... If I remember right than these two default destination was for us too.

Answer (score 4):

You can try determining where your version of python is installed first (dynamically) by doing:

```
import os                   
print(os.environ['path'])
```

It'll yield all the path information of your current system (in Windows OS). Then you can parse that text output and make sense out of it.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use `sys.executable` to determine the specific Python executable being run?

Comment: The problem is not determining, that where does anaconda / miniconda installs itself on _my computer_, but on _general_, to what location could it be installed, if the user accepts the default location provided?

Answer (score 2):

I just (Oct 23, 2020) installed miniconda3 on windows using `winget install miniconda3` and it installed in `C:\Users\<username>\Miniconda3`.

Answer (score 1):

On Jan 18, 2023 it installed to C:\Users<username>\AppData\Local\miniconda3 for the 64bit version.